# Bring an imageView to top in framelayout

Tags: android

I have a framelayout in which there is surfaceView and an ImageView, the ImageView being invisible .Based on some event the ImageView has to become visible. But it isnt coming to the foreground. I know the image has become visible as i can see in the logs but its not showing because its not on the top, the SurfaceView is. So how can I bring the ImageView to the top?? Here is my code.

public void onClick(View v) {

```
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Button1) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lockIcon1);

        if(!icon1show) {
            icon1show = true;
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            icon1show = false;
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }else if( v.getId() == R.id.Button2) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lockIcon2);

        if(!icon2show) {
            icon2show = true;
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else {
            icon2show = false;
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }
}
```

XML code:

```
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/lockIcon2"
                        android:src="@drawable/lockicon"
                        android:visibility = "invisible"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/far_end"
                        android:layout_height="217.33dip" android:layout_width="291dip"/>



    </FrameLayout>
```

Now the image from "lockIcon2" is not showing as there is a SurfaceView along with that imageView in a frameLayout. So please help !!

Comment: Do you need SurfaceView visible with imageView???

Comment: yes i need the imageview to be visible on top of the SurfaceView

Comment: ok i got it !!..put a surfaceView.setBackGroundColor(Color.TRANSPERANT) on the surfaceView, den it allows the showing of ImageView, dats pretty weird!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a snippet of code so we can help you. Do you use the `bringToFront()`method?

Comment: Hi, I added th code as you requested. I tried using bringToFront() method but no use !!

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand you fully but I think that you need to put your SurfaceView gone, not invisible. When invisible it will occupy place on screen. Try this...

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that solved this issue for me using requestTransparentRegion() call.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904508/233048