# View1 disappears after View2.setvisibility(view.INVISIBLE) just on Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-asynctask, visibility, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, glsurfaceview

in my APP I got a gametaskbar which holds specific gamecontrols (control_1, control_2). Additionaly I have two Buttons (Button_1, Button_2) where I can switch visibility. Because I have a lot of UI-Changes, I do this visibility-switching in onPostexecute() of an asynctask.
This works well on all tested devices prior android 4.0. But >4.0 devices delete the background-image of my gametaskbar when switching visibility of one of the buttons.
This shouldn`t happen and I have no more ideas where to look.

I have a framelayout with glsurfaceview on bottom of the view hierarchy.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/baseframe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/glSurfaceHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GameTaskbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/control_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blind" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/control_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blind" >
    </Button>   
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_1"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_64"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_2"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back_64"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
</Button>
</FrameLayout>
```

this is the part where I switch visibilty:

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
if(button_1_state){
    Button_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
    Button_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
if(button_2_state){
    Button_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
    Button_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

...
 }
```

According to this post ( [Error when refreshing View on top of SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891262/error-when-refreshing-view-on-top-of-surfaceview) ) I was able to reduce the Android4.0 specific unwanted behaviour to the unwanted backgroundvisibilityswitch.

I`ve also tried requestFocus() on the buttons without luck.

When I debug it, everything looks like it should and gametaskbar.getVisibility() = 0. But after leaving the async-onPostexecute() the backgroundimage disappear. When I do not switch buttonvisibility to invisible in this situation, the backgroundimage will also stay. Like I use wrong IDs which I do not.

Even in the emulator I can reproduce this behaviour.

ps: the buttonvisibility changes as wanted

Maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this: 
changed LinearLayout with backgrundimage of the GameTaskBar to another FrameLayout with Imageview underneath the original LinearLayout with controls

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/GameTaskbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/bar_512_2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bar"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/control_1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blind" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/control_2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blind" >
        </Button>   
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

ornay